# Force gateway for IP connection

Tags: windows, sockets, networking

I have two NICs in my Windows PC, one for Internet and the other for outbound UDP streams.  Both NICs have gateways and I tweak the metrics so that Internet bound traffic goes to the first.  I would rather disable the gateway on the second NIC and specify the gateway when I create the UDP socket.  Is this possible?  Can I force the destination MAC address on a socket?

Comment: When you create and bind to your socket don't use INADDR_ANY, use the actual IP address assigned to the NIC you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [`bind()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550.aspx) the socket to the local IP address of the NIC you want to use.  If you don't know the IP, use [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) to enumerate the NICs until you find the one you want, and then you will know its current IP to bind to.

Comment: Sorry I made an error when writing the question. I don't want to specify only the NIC, but also the gateway.

Comment: @BrunoMartinez: that is not how sockets work. You can't specify a gateway, only the local network interface to use for transmitting and receiving.  So you have to bind to the interface that is connected to the desired gateway.  `GetAdaptersInfo()` and `GetAdaptersAddresses()` both include gateway information, so you can look for that.

Comment: But having two NICs, both with gateways, is a pain. You have to tweak the metrics. A special NIC that we use (DekTec 2162) allows to set the gateway per connection.

Comment: @BrunoMartinez: Good for it. There is no socket API to accomplish that per connection. You have to find the interface that is connected to the gateway, then bind the socket to that interface before you then start reading/sending packets over that interface.